# How to input cents with mottie keyboard and keep them there?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, keyboard, uikeyboard

I am going crazy over here... I've invested over 16 hours trying to get this thing to work, if anyone has any clue of the reason of this evil behavior please advice..

I have multiple inputs of type number inside a form where I attached the keyboard to each input like this:

```
$('.amount').keyboard({
    layout: 'custom',
    customLayout : {
      'normal' : ['1 2 3', '4 5 6', '7 8 9','{clear} 0 {bksp}','{accept}']
    },

    display : {
      'accept' : 'Confirm:Confirm (Shift-Enter)',
      'bksp' : 'Delete:Delete',
      'clear': 'Clear:Clear'
    },

    beforeVisible: function(e, keyboard, el) {
      $("#"+keyboard.$keyboard[0].id).addClass("hide-me");
    },

    restrictInput: true,
    preventPaste: true,
    autoAccept: true,
    usePreview: false,
    useWheel: false,
    repeatRate: 0,

    // this function is so I can display cents in the input
    // there is no decimal in the keyboard as part of the requirements
    change: function(e, keyboard, el) {
        if (el.value === null || el.value === "") {
            el.value = "0.00";
        }

        el.value = parseInt(el.value);
        el.value = el.value * 0.01;
    },

    // this function is so I can display cents in the inputs
    // there is no decimal in the keyboard as part of the requirements
    accepted: function(e, keyboard, el) {
        if (el.value === null || el.value === "") {
            el.value = "0.00";
        }

        el.value = parseInt(el.value);
        el.value = el.value * 0.01;
    },

    caretToEnd: 'true',
    maxLength : '20',
    css: {
      container: 'center-block dropdown-menu custom-keypad',
      buttonDefault: 'btn-kb',
      buttonHover: 'btn-primary',
      buttonAction: 'active',
      buttonDisabled: 'disabled'
    }
});
```

Keyboard pops up as it should, I can see the decimals in my input correctly as I type and as I confirm my input. My goal is to sum all the input.val() and validate them as soon any change happens on the form. That functionality to do that is like this:

```
    $('form').on('change', '.amount', function () {
        var balance = NUMBER;
        var sum = 0;

        $(".amount").each(function (){
            var valTotal = Number($(this).val());
            if (!isNaN(valTotal)) {
                sum += valTotal;
            }
        });

        if (sum > balance) {
           //stuff happens
        }

    });//.end of form
```

Here is where the problem starts, when I go to sum the inputs, my decimals disappear! what was 22.22 is now 2222 so my sum is wrong, causing my sum to be always larger that my balance. I tried to create a fiddle but it won't pop the keyboard on the result box so I can't show you a live example..

This are the CDN's I'm using:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.26.17/js/jquery.keyboard.extension-all.min.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.26.17/js/jquery.keyboard.min.js

PLEASE ADVICE!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got in touch with the creator of the plugin and he was kind enough to answer my question via email. His solution worked perfectly!

You can see the fiddle right here..
http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/egb3a1sk/2506/

```
/* VIRTUAL KEYBOARD DEMO - https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard */
$(function() {

  // this function is so I can display cents in the input
  // there is no decimal in the keyboard as part of the requirements
  function convert(el) {
    var value = el.value;
    if (el.value === null || el.value === "") {
      value = "0.00";
    }
    value = parseInt(value, 10);
    value = value * 0.01;
    el.value = value.toFixed(2);
  }

  NUMBER = 100;
  function sum() {
    var balance = NUMBER;
    var sum = 0;
    $(".amount:not(:disabled)").each(function() {
      var valTotal = Number($(this).val());
      if (!isNaN(valTotal)) {
        sum += valTotal;
      }
    });
    if (sum > balance) {
      //stuff happens
    }
    $('.sum').text(sum);
  }

  $('.amount').keyboard({
    layout: 'custom',
    customLayout: {
      'normal': ['1 2 3', '4 5 6', '7 8 9', '{clear} 0 {bksp}', '{accept}']
    },

    display: {
      'accept': 'Confirm:Confirm (Shift-Enter)',
      'bksp': 'Delete:Delete',
      'clear': 'Clear:Clear'
    },

    beforeVisible: function(e, keyboard, el) {
      $("#" + keyboard.$keyboard[0].id).addClass("hide-me");
    },

    restrictInput: true,
    preventPaste: true,
    autoAccept: true,
    usePreview: false,
    useWheel: false,
    repeatRate: 0,

    change: function(e, keyboard, el) {
      convert(el);
    },
    accepted: function(e, keyboard, el) {
      convert(el);
      sum();
    },

    caretToEnd: 'true',
    maxLength: '20',
    css: {
      container: 'center-block dropdown-menu custom-keypad',
      buttonDefault: 'btn-kb',
      buttonHover: 'btn-primary',
      buttonAction: 'active',
      buttonDisabled: 'disabled'
    }

  });

});
```

The main issue was that the $('.amount') selector was including a hidden duplicate input so he changed it to $(".amount:not(:disabled)")
And he also performed the sum() operation right after the formatting happened on 'accepted'

Worked perfectly =)